# Why does the default styling on a HTML5 <progress> bar have vertical-align?

Tags: css, html

The default stylesheet for [Webkit](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/html.css#L1035) puts the vertical alignment on a `<progress>` element to be -0.2em. Why -0.2em rather than 0?

Comment: It does? Please show the webkit spec for your source.

Comment: Perhaps you should be asking Webkit, unless someone here actually wrote that

Comment: Firefox does that too.

Comment: @Paulie_D the site takes forever to load, but it's on line 1035

Comment: If they did not put vertical align on the element at all then it defaults to baseline which aligns the bottom of the progress bar to the bottom of the text. This does not look bad but with the -0.2em it vertically centers the progress to the text. You can always change the value if you like

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interesting question. According to `vertical-align` [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) when the value is specified as a length then it

> Aligns the baseline of the element at the given length above the baseline of its parent.

By default the height of the `progress` element defined as `1em`. This means that making it `-0.2em` ensures that progress bar stays perfectly alligned vertically with adjacent inline/inline-block elements.

```js
var progress = document.querySelector('progress');
setInterval(function() {
  progress.classList.toggle('va0');
}, 2000);
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 2em;
}
progress {
  width: 200px;
}
.va0 {
  vertical-align: 0;
}
div:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  content: '<progress> vertical-align: -0.2em';
}
.va0 ~ div:after {
  content: '<progress> vertical-align: 0';
}
```

```html
<progress></progress> Some text.
<div></div>
```

Try making progress bar `vertical-align: 0` and you will see that it no longer looks nice next to its inline neighbors.

Comment: This worked great! I was using the jQuery UI progress bar. Adding -0.2em vertical-align made it look right inline. Thanks!